# AngularJs generate categories from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<table class="table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-if="$index%3==0" ng-repeat="permission in vm.parent.getAllPermissions()">
            <td ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]" class="col-xs-2">
                <span>
                <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="vm.data.permissions" checklist-value="vm.parent.getPermission($parent.$index+i)"> 
                {{vm.parent.getPermissionTitle($parent.$index+i) || " "}}
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

that's my angularjs for now. My json is like this. There are N users, and categories and and permissions

```
{
  "Admin": {
    "category": "admin",
    "permission": "admin"
  },
  "user": {
    "category": "user",
    "permission": "user"
  }
}
```

`vm.getAllPermissions()` returns all the data. I want to split the users and the permissions, so basically I want to have the categories split into `ui-tab` and under each tab the permissions displayed as a table.

I have tried something like this

```
var permissionArray =[];
Object.keys(vmgetAllPermissions).map(function(category, key) {

for(var key in vmgetAllPermissions) {
    if(vmgetAllPermissions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        permissionArray.push(category,key);

    }
}

});
```

It doesn't work but it gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do. the view looks like this

[image]

category admin, tab at the top, list of permissions where the checkboxes are. I'm pretty sure all I have to do is provide category as a parameter to `vm.parent.getAllPermissions` but I'm not that good at angular nor JS, I prefer to ask you.

Comment: I'm on the road, if you have any questions, please let me know and I'll clarify everything in 3h from now. No internet connection

Comment: How does `allData` look like ? Is it the map that you have posted ?

Comment: @AminMeyghani yes basically java sends json, objects, they need to be mapped to array, my representation is just to show you how json looks like but basically it needs mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is you need to push one value at a time -- push an **object**. So your code would look like this: (just add the curly braces)

```
permissionArray.push({category,key});
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/yh0ugp6q/1/

Comment: it was a far bigger problem than that but i'll accept your answer since I solved the issue - I had to map the objects